# sub-select query in SQL will not populated new column/field with specific text

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How do I get my new field to populate with Yes or No rather than pre-existing data? In this case, I'm getting a new field called ESL but I can only get it to run if i populated the field with colleagueId. I want it to populate with Yes and not true with No.  I've also tried case statements.

```
select distinct s.colleagueId,  st.enrollmentStatus, 
s.firstEnrolledTerm,  ESL.colleagueId as ESL

from tbl_studentTerms st

left join

(select distinct colleagueId
from tbl_studentclasses 
where enrolled = 1
and subject = 'ESL') as ESL

on ESL.colleagueId=st.colleagueId


inner join tbl_students s
on st.colleagueId = s.colleagueId
where s.endingCohort = '2009SP' 
and st.term='2009SP'
and s.colleagueId in(select [Student ID] from dbo.pvt_SelectedStudents)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method:

```
select distinct s.colleagueId,  st.enrollmentStatus, 
       s.firstEnrolledTerm,
       coalesce(ESL.ESL, 'No') as ESL
from tbl_studentTerms st inner join
     tbl_students s
     on st.colleagueId = s.colleagueId left join
     (select distinct colleagueId, 'Yes' as ESL
      from tbl_studentclasses 
      where enrolled = 1 and subject = 'ESL'
     ) ESL
     on ESL.colleagueId = st.colleagueId 
where s.endingCohort = '2009SP' and st.term = '2009SP' and
      s.colleagueId in (select [Student ID] from dbo.pvt_SelectedStudents);
```

Notes:

- I move the `inner join` to be before the `left join`.  I find it easiest to read query where `inner join`s come first, followed by `left join`s.
- Do not use `select distinct` unless you really need to remove duplicates.

Comment: Can I use this coalesce function with aggregate function?  For example, how do I return another column with a count of something.  The following works on its own, but as soon as I put it into a more complex query, like the one above that joins multiple tables, I can't get it to work.           
     select colleagueId, COUNT(*) AS BIO203Att
      from tbl_studentclasses 
      where enrolled = 1 and subject = 'BIO' and coursenumber ='203' 
      and colleagueId in (select [Student ID] from dbo.pvt_SelectedStudents)
      group by colleagueId

Comment: @marmode . . . If you want to use an aggregation function, then I would expect a `group by`.

Comment: Thank you!  it worked when i did a subquery with a group by!  Like this ---number of attempts of BIO203 
     
  left join   
   (select colleagueId, COUNT(*) AS BIO203Att
      from tbl_studentclasses 
      where enrolled = 1 and subject = 'BIO' and coursenumber ='203' 
      group by colleagueId
      ) BIO203Att
      on BIO203Att.colleagueId = s.colleagueId